# Getting 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined' using toastr

Tags: javascript, toastr

I issued `toastr.error("a message")` but got this error. It happens in `_setContainer` when it does `$animate.enter().then(function())`.
What am I missing?

```
function _setContainer(options) {
  if(container) { return containerDefer.promise; } // If the container is there, don't create it.

  container = angular.element('<div></div>');
  container.attr('id', options.containerId);
  container.addClass(options.positionClass);
  container.css({'pointer-events': 'auto'});
  var body = $document.find('body').eq(0);
  $animate.enter(container, body).then(function() {
    containerDefer.resolve();
  });
  return containerDefer.promise;
}
```

Comment: where is `container`, `containerDefer`, `$animate` defined?

Comment: Also just ran into this. the $animate.enter code is new to Angular 1.3, I think. You need to use 1.2 branch

Comment: Thanks Jay! I've now realized I can't just install whatever Bower grabs for me.

Answer (score 2):

The version of angular-toastr that is supported with angular@1.2 is 0.3.0